# Event after all ajax calls are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I have a click event that fires off 3 ajax calls:

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax(call1);
    $.ajax(call2);
    $.ajax(call3);

    some_function() //should fire off AFTER all ajax calls are complete
});
```

Is there a way for me to confirm all ajax calls have been fired BEFORE firing off my `some_function()` function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you care if they succeed?

Comment: No, i don't care if they succeed @NeilTwist

Comment: The only way to confirm that they have been fired is to handle the response. You can ignore the data itself as in my answer. Set an appropriate timeout if response time is an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

```
$.when($.ajax(call1), $.ajax(call2), $.ajax(call3))
.done(function () {
     some_function();
});
```

---

If (for some reason) you have an array of promises, then you may call this method using [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
$.when.apply($, ajaxArray)
.done(function () {
   some_function();
});
```

Comment: If you have an array of promises, why not just use `Promise.all()`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `async: false` and put the `$.ajax` inside another ajax, somelike this...

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    // ...
    complete: function() {
        $.ajax({ // second ajax
            async: false,
            // ...
            complete: function() {
                $.ajax({ // second ajax
                    async: false,
                    // ...
                    complete: function() {
                         some_function();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why does this need to set `async: false`?

Comment: to ensure that despite the success of each request is followed by the above

Comment: Ah ok, I would prefer to suggest that errors are handled, but I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you require success responses, but consider the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://some.url.example.com/endpoint",
})
.always(function (data){
    // Process the data
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://some.url.example.com/endpoint2",
    })
    .always(function (data2){
        // Process the data
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://some.url.example.com/endpoint3",
        })
        .always(function (data) {
            someFunction();
        });
    });
});
```

There is a lot more reading that could be done about jQuery deferred objects and ES6 Promises.

If you wish to set a timeout and don't care about the result, set the timeout option `$.ajax({url: "http://some.url.example.com/endpoint", timeout: 500})

OR

Set a variable in each and use `window.setTimeout` to check when they've all been set, but that is horrible.